# XSLT 1.0 Add Elements Increment ID

Tags: xml, xslt

With XML:

```
<Table>
    <Row id=1>
       <Col1>...</Col1>
       <Col2>...</Col2>
    </Row>
    <Row id=2>
       <Col1>...</Col1>
       <Col2>...</Col2>
    </Row>
</Table>
```

How can I add new Row elements at the end and increment the id attribute using XSLT 1.0?  The source XML may have any number of Row elements.

```
<Table>
    <Row id=1>
       <Col1>...</Col1>
       <Col2>...</Col2>
    </Row>
    <Row id=2>
       <Col1>...</Col1>
       <Col2>...</Col2>
    </Row>
    <Row id=3>
       <Col1>...</Col1>
       <Col2>...</Col2>
    </Row>
    <Row id=4>
       <Col1>...</Col1>
       <Col2>...</Col2>
    </Row>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a template for the `Table` element that reads out `Row[last()]/@id + 1` and adds a new `Row` or if needed more `Row`s:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="number-of-rows-to-add" select="5"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="add-rows">
                <xsl:with-param name="current-index" select="Row[last()]/@id + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="number-of-rows-to-add" select="$number-of-rows-to-add"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="add-rows">
        <xsl:param name="current-index"/>
        <xsl:param name="number-of-rows-to-add"/>
        <Row id="{$current-index}">
            <Col1>...</Col1>
            <Col2>...</Col2>
        </Row>
        <xsl:if test="$number-of-rows-to-add > 1">
            <xsl:call-template name="add-rows">
                <xsl:with-param name="current-index" select="$current-index + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="number-of-rows-to-add" select="$number-of-rows-to-add - 1"/>                
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38YX.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The ColX elements will have varying text, but this gives me some ideas.  I like the xsltransform.net link.  Haven't seen that tool before.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve my problem. I'm still looking it over.  Not sure why, but it doesn't work in the xsltransform.net tool.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my:my" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name='last-id' select="Table/Row[last()]/@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/my:rows/*">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$last-id + position()"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <my:rows>
        <Row>
            <Col1>A</Col1>
            <Col2>B</Col2>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Col1>C</Col1>
            <Col2>D</Col2>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Col1>E</Col1>
            <Col2>F</Col2>
        </Row>
    </my:rows>
</xsl:transform>
```